# How to get all the key value pairs in modelMap object , inside spring controller itself , returned by modelAndView.getModel() in java spring framework

Tags: java, spring, modelandview

Map modelMap = modelAndView.getModel();

I want to retrieve all the keys in the modelMap object , so that i can access each values , these values can be assigned to variables/objects created in the controller class itself

Comment: You already have a map.So u r asking how to iterate through the keys of a map.you can use keyset() or entryset()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModelMap subclasses `LinkedHashMap` which in turns extends `HashMap`

The generic type of ModelMap is fixed at `Map<String, Object>`

So you can iterate through the keys of a map as in `HashMap`, you can use keyset() or entryset()

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

*

Answer (score 0):

The runtime class of Map returned by modelAndView.getModel() is  org.springframework.ui.ModelMap .This class extends LinkedHashMap without changing the keyset() or entryset() methods.Just use keySet() or entrySet()